# Why don't Live Wallpapers display correctly on a Samsung Epic 4G?

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I have a very odd problem where live wallpapers will not work right on a Samsung Epic 4G.

It works fine in the emulator as well as other phones running both 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3.3.

I can not reproduce the problem in an emulator to try and fix it, and I really don't want to buy an epic 4G, because I'm not on Sprint.

The wallpaper is placed to the far right of the screen and it does not scroll. Again, on every other WVGA800 screen it works as intended which doesn't make sense.

Another thing to note is that these wallpapers did work correctly before Sprint's last update.

my offsets look like

```
@Override

public void on OffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                              float xOffsetStep, yOffsetStep,
                              Offset, yPixelOffset) {

  super onOffsetsChanged(xOffset, yOffset, xOffsetStep, 
                         yOffsetStep, xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);

  displayTransform.setTranslate(xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);
}
```

It turns out my sister has one of these phones and she has let me borrow it.

I tried changing the size and placement of the background multiple examples like cube wallpaper I changed the options in her phone so it has 5 screens instead of 7 nothing will work I have no idea what to try next.

Its only on this phone I'm getting a lot of emails from people telling me how much they like the wallpaper but the people who have downloaded it on epic 4g/galaxy S it will not work

Update: If I change

```
displayTranform.setTranslate(xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset)
```

to

```
displayTransform.setTranslate(xPixelOffset-220, yPixelOffset)
```

it will center the wallpaper, it still wont scroll if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I Figured it out! I added

```
xPixelOffset = -220
if(Xoffset < 0.5f){
    xPixelOffset = xPixelOffset + 98
}
if (Xoffset < .02f){
    xPixelOffset = xPixelOffset +115
}
```

ect.

I figured if xOffset was returning values and xPixelOffset wasn't I'd just do it manualy

They put a custom launcer on this phone and it doesnt return values the same as the one provided by adroid.

Comment: They also don't seem to set getDesiredMinimumWidth() and getDesiredMinimumHeight(), they both just return -1.  I'm amazed any of the stock live wallpapers work.  I guess they're ignoring those values and using xOffset instead of xPixelOffset.